# Plotting in Python matplotlib with interleaved xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

This question is regarding plotting in matplotlib with xticks - Python.

Lets say I have three vectors:

X = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ] with corresponding labels LVEC = [a,b,c,d,e]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5]

I would like to plot X,Y but provide interleaved xticks from LVEC (ie., only a,c,e labels show on the plot). The graph should, however, consist of all the five data points. Is this possible natively?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

X = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ] 
LVEC = ['a','b','c','d','e'] 
Y = [1,2,3,4,5]

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(111)  # or pl.gca() or similar
pl.plot(X, Y, '-x')
ax.set_xticks([X[0],X[2],X[4]])
ax.set_xticklabels([LVEC[0],LVEC[2],LVEC[4]])
```

So the main trick is to first specify the x-locations where the labels should occur with `set_xticks`, and next the overwrite the labels with `set_xticklabels`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should give you the effect you want.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X,Y, c='white',edgecolors='None')
for i, txt in enumerate(LVEC):
    ax.annotate(txt, (X[i],Y[i]))
```